# Prevent apps form close by phone key. Like "Todder Lock" apps

Tags: android

As titile, I don not want to close apps by any key on android phone. Can I close it by clicking on custom button in activity.

Comment: You can close it via a custom button by calling finish().  To prevent it from closing due to the home key, you'd need an entire custom ROM.

Comment: Thanks. But it is not what I need

Comment: I'm making an app for restaurant and I don't want customer exits the app by clicking phone's keys, So I have the same question as well, anyone can help?